# Index.php using BASEURL to connect to inner pages connection issue htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having an issue with connecting the inner pages to the index.php file. It uses BASEURL.

There was a snippet of code that went missing (in the .htaccess file) that basically said call for index.php when you request for the inner pages such as /about-us.

There was a RewriteCond and RewriteRule in the snippet.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301
```

I know this is suppose to point all URLs  from non-www to www. But it was in a similar format to this.

Comment: Post your code sniplet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in .htaccess filer in your root directory. Rewrite any none existing url to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.htaccessredirect.net/ to create redirect condition for you if you have know knowledg of `htacces` redirects.You can also use below code if you have enabled `SymLinks` in your apache configuration

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: The index.php is still working, but placing this in the htaccess wouldn't break the page will it? I'm fairly new to htaccess.

Comment: Nope its just redirection rule that will point all request to your `index.php` , then your `index.php` can tell what to do with that rule .

Comment: If it were not to work, removing it will reverse the change correct?